# Problema de [Error] 'Cola' does not name a type C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, nodos

Estoy desarrollando actualmente un  proyecto en C++ y mi problema está en que cuando voy a compilar me sale un error `does not name type` en la línea 4 del fichero **.cpp** que colocaré a continuación.

Y mientras tanto en el código del .h tengo lo siguiente. Tuve que incluir la clase al final porque si no también me daba un error por los templates.

Ya he acomodado la mayoría de los errores pero este en verdad que no lo encuentro. Me gustaría que me ayudaran con la explicación de a qué se debe este error, debido a que la plantilla nos la exige un profesor y no he cambiado nada de su código pero me sale error.

```
template <class Tipo>
Cola<Tipo>::Cola(Tipo info, nodo *prox) {
    Frente = '/0';
    Final = '/0';
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Cola<Tipo>::Vacia() {
    return Frente == '/0';
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Cola<Tipo>::Llena() {
    nodo<Tipo> *p;
    p = new nodo<Tipo>;
    if (p == '/0')
        return true;
    else
    {
        delete p;
        return false;
    }
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Cola<Tipo>::Insertar(Tipo Valor) {
    nodo<Tipo> *nuevo;
    if (!Llena())
    {
        nuevo = new nodo<Tipo>;
        nuevo->info = Valor;
        nuevo->prox = '/0';
        if (Final == '/0') 
            Frente = nuevo;       
        else Final->prox = nuevo;
        Final = nuevo;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
};

template <class Tipo>
bool Cola<Tipo>::Remover(Tipo &Valor) {
    nodo<Tipo> *primero;
    if (!Vacia())
    {
        primero = Frente;
        Valor = primero->info;
        Frente = primero->prox;
        if (Frente == '/0')
            Final = '/0';
        delete primero;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
};
```

```
template <class Tipo>
class Cola;

template <class Tipo>
class nodo {
    Tipo info;
    nodo *prox;
    friend class Cola<Tipo>;
};

template <class Tipo>
class Cola
{
        nodo<Tipo> *Frente,*Final;
    public:
        Cola(Tipo info, nodo *prox);
        bool Vacia();
        bool Llena();
        bool Insertar(Tipo Valor);
        bool Remover(Tipo &Valor);
};

#include "Cola.cpp"
```

Comment: Me da la impresión de que has tenido que incluir el .cpp en el .hpp porque estás compilando el .hpp en vez del otro. Lo habitual es incluir el .hpp dentro del .cpp, como una de las primeras líneas de código, y compilar el fichero .cpp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cola(Tipo info, nodo *prox);
                ^^^^
```

`nodo` no es un tipo. `nodo` es un template. `nodo<Tipo>` es  un tipo.

```
Cola<Tipo>::Cola(Tipo info, nodo *prox) {
```

Lo mismo aquí, y olvidaste `template <class Tipo>`.

`'/0'` no tiene sentido. Quieres usar `nullptr` en su lugar.

Hay *muchos* otros problemas, espero que esto te ayude a comenzar.

Comment: muchas gracias en verdad y buen me ayuda mucho porque ese ejemplo no lo cree yo me lo dio un profesor